# Is it OK to resolve promise error to higher order promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Is it OK to resolve promise error to higher order promise
EX

```
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   //call async function

   await async_function(resolve, reject);
})

const async_function = async (resolve, reject) => {
  // some code 
  get_data_from_db
     .then(data => resolve(null,data))
     .catch(e => resolve(e, null)
}
```

get_data_from_db can call other async functions.
reject didn't return error to the higher promise

Comment: if you have a reason for it (eg you patch an application which uses callbacks that expect a certain order of arguments). It is fine, provided you can know at all times in your application when promise was successful and when it failed

Comment: *"reject didn't return error to the higher promise"* – Because you're never calling `reject` anywhere…!?

Comment: That's not the way you're supposed to use `async/await`. You pass a `resolve, reject` to a promise constructor, but the beauty of `async/await` is that your returns and error throws are automagically transformed into respectively resolves and rejects!

Answer (score 0):

As `await` works on non-promises as well, you can save the whole `Promise` construct:

```
const async_function = () => get_data_from_db(); 

(async()=>{
    try {
        //call async function
        const data = await async_function();
        console.log(data);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to resolve promise

sometimes it's ok. Think about a rejected promise as an "async-throw" and a catch-block for it

but your code is an example of antipattern http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern

```
const async_function = async (resolve, reject) => {
  // some code 
  get_data_from_db
     .then(data => resolve(null,data))
     .catch(e => resolve(e, null)
}
```

you can rewrite it like:

```
const async_function = () =>
  get_data_from_db()
     .catch(e => e) // it will be resolved with e
```